# Simple DELETE statement did not work

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete

I have a table MRU, that has 3 columns.

```
(VALUE varchar(255); TYPE varchar(20); DT_ADD datetime)
```

This is a table simply storing an entry and recording the date time it was recorded. What I wanted to do is: delete the oldest entry whenever I add a new entry that exceeds a certain number.

Here is my query:

```
delete from MRU 
where type = 'FILENAME' 
ORDER BY DT_ADD limit 1;
```

The error message is:
SQL Error: near "ORDER": syntax error ...

The query returns an error.

Comment: Did it return just "an error" or perhaps "a specific error"? Can you post the error message?

Comment: Why do you have an ORDER BY on a delete?

Comment: @Oded - Its possible to do that.  The SQLite syntax allows you to have an ORDER BY in the DELETE.  Its semantically okay.

Comment: The awful "an error" error message is so painful. It's right up there with the "it doesn't work" exception. Hate when that happens.

Comment: You may want to place an ASCENDING after DT_ADD to ensure that the oldest entry will actually be the first one in the ordering.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: If neither ASC nor DESC is specified, ASC(ending) is implied.

Comment: who would up vote this question?? it lacks a very important item, ah, the actual error message!

Comment: I voted up this question. I have a rule for my own usage of Stack Overflow. If I post an answer, I upvote the question. At the very least, the poster captured enough of my attention to warrant an answer-post, and thus I upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not saying that you should do so, since it's completely non-portable, but if there's a compelling need, this will work:

In SQLite the rowid column always exists unless an integer primary key is defined elsewhere. This can be used in something like:

```
delete from MRU where rowid = (
    select rowid from MRU order by DT_ADD limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it always helps posting as much information as you have. In this particular instance, "an error" is unhelpful and it would've taken you perhaps 2 seconds to copy and paste the actual error message given, which would give us valuable clues when helping you.

Instead, I went to the documentation for the DELETE statement of SQLite, found [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html), and notice that lo and behold, DELETE does not have ORDER BY, unless it is compiled in a specific manner. I assume your version isn't, although without the error message it is hard to tell.

What you can try instead is this:

```
delete from MRU where DT_ADD = (
    SELECT MIN(DT_ADD) FROM MRU WHERE type = 'FILENAME'
)
```

Comment: Note, though, that the table declaration given doesn't contain a single column that we can assume to be the primary key.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that, rewriting as we speak.

Comment: lack of PK is probably why they want to use `limit 1`. It would be better to just fix the design and `DELETE ... WHERE ID=n`

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the answers. The error message says syntax error near "ORDER". Do you mean order doesn't work for all version of SQLite, just certain version that were compiled specifically have order by?

Comment: Can someone explain th significance of no primary key and delete in SQLite?

Comment: Rev 2 of this answer won't work, as it will delete *all* records that have the min(dt_add) value.  user only wants to delete a single one.  user will have to add some sort of identifier to the table to get this to work (and use rev 1's DDL SQL) or recompile the SQLite library with SSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT set.  I recommend the former.

Comment: Considering that the table is named "MRU", for Most Recently Used, I seriously doubt there will be more than one entry with any given date-time for "when added". If there is, then yes, a redesign is a good idea. Mind you, a redesign to get a unique primary key is a good decision in any way.